# Converting decimal to binary error

Tags: java

I wanted to convert decimal to binary and the following code doesn't work.
Please help me to correct the code.

```
package mainpackage;

import java.util.*;

class MainClass {

public MainClass() {
}

public static int binaryfinder(int n) {
    int a[] = new int[8];
    int i = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int n1 = n;
    while (n1 > 0) {
        a[i] = n1 % 2;
        i++;
        n1 = n1 / 2;
    }
    System.out.printf("Binary number of %d is = ", n);

    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            b += ((10 ^ j) * a[j]);
    }
    return b;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number to find its binary value:\n");
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = k.nextInt();
    int inBin = binaryfinder(num);
    System.out.print(inBin);


}
```

}

After I click RUN, it asks to enter the binary value and when I enter the value, it says, "**Binary number of 0 =** " No matter what I enter it always outputs "**Binary number of 0 =** ". 
No errors are thrown.

Comment: Pretty sure `while (j != 0) {
                b += ((10 ^ j) * a[j]);
            }` runs forever.

Comment: Is it a homework. If not then there are inline ways to find binary.

Comment: This is where using your debugger to debug your program would help you find the issues you have.

Comment: I assume you cannot just do `Integer.toBinaryString(num);`

Comment: The correct platform for such questions are
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your A array is only 8 elements, limiting you to an input of 256.  `(10 ^ j)` is exclusive-ORing the two values, probably not what you want.  And that's as far as I got.

Comment: There is no decimal here.  `nextInt()` returns binary. `int` is binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer.toBinaryString(i)
```

this should do the trick in java

Answer (score 0):

You have an endless loop, thats why your program never terminates:

```
while (j != 0) {
    b += ((10 ^ j) * a[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> After I click RUN, it asks to enter the binary value and when I enter the value, it says, "Binary number of 0 = " No matter what I enter it always outputs "Binary number of 0 = ". No errors are thrown.

- Never ending `while` loop

  `while (j != 0) {
      b += ((10 ^ j) * a[j]);
  }`
- You are changing value of `n` and finally after `while` loop :`n = 0` and so the output

  `while (n > 0) {
      a[i] = n % 2;
      i++;
      n = n / 2;
  }
  System.out.println(output);`
- Your program (as whole) is incorrect

> Other Options:

1)      Use `Integer.toBinaryString()`

2)      Use the basic formula to convert decimal --> binary

```
int n = 10;
String output = "";

do {
  output = (n % 2) + output; // reverse string 
  n = n / 2;
} while (n > 0);
```